# How to install and build with libxml library

Tags: debian, compilation, libraries

I am trying to use libxml in a program. I have installed libxml2 and libxml2-dev. The library declaration in the program is

```
#include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
```

and the build flag is `-lxml2`.

The compiler returns an error that there is no such file or directory. When I use

```
dpkg -L lxml
```

the `libxml2` folder and files are similar to those of other libraries that are used with the program. curl for example:

```
__@______:/usr/share/doc/curl $ tree
.
├── changelog.Debian.gz
├── changelog.gz
├── copyright
└── NEWS.Debian.gz
```

Where are the library files being used. Are the build flag or library declarations incorrect?

Update
per the post recommended in the comment, this flag:

```
-I/usr/include/libxml2
```

allowed the program to build with only the library declaration in the program. When the library's function calls are added to the program, the build fails with errors like

```
undefined reference to 'htmlParseChunk'
```

Comment: @cherdt yes, the flag -I/usr/include/libxml2/ worked.